# How run Python script that it is in S3 using lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to run a python code that I have in my S3 bucket using AWS lambda

I tried with `os` library, but it have not worked out

My code is:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    os.system('python https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/BUCKET/CODE.py')
```

I get the message "No such file or directory"

I am using lambda because the code in python must be triggered when some event happends

How can I run my code?

Comment: Why do you have Python code that is trying to call Python code? Can't you incorporate the code into your actual AWS Lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think it is going to happen if you run `python http://google.com.py` on your machine?

It's going to try to run a file called `http://google.com.py` on the current working directory.

It's impossible for both `os.system` and `python` to determine whether the argument is an URL, and, if it is, download and execute its contents.

You will have to [get](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html) your S3 file using boto3, write its contents inside `/tmp` (this is the only *writable* directory inside Lambda functions) and finally invoke it like:

```
os.system('python /tmp/myscript.py')
```